# How do I resolve "cannot add bindings to a locked environment" when working with setRefClass in R

Tags: r, unit-testing, oop, testthat

I have a function in R as follows

```
DrawDistroGenerationClass <- function(in_hourStr, in_data){
  
  me <- methods::setRefClass(
    ## Define the environment where this list is defined so
    ## that I can refer to it later.
    "Draw",
    fields = list(hourStr = "character",
                  data = "numeric"),
    
    methods = list(
      getModel = function(){
        return("Draw Distro")
    },
      getName = function(){
        return(hourStr)
    },
      #' 
      #' @param strName the data to be drawn from
      #' @return the new hours value
      generateHoursFromStorage = function(strName){
  

        indSelect <- stats::runif(1, min = 1, max = length(data))
          
        componentLife <- data[indSelect]
        
        return(componentLife)
    }
    )
  )
  ## Set the name for the class
  newMe <- me$new(hourStr = in_hourStr, data = in_data)
  return(newMe)
}
```

The test looks like...

```
test_that("test Time2Repair-DrawDistroHoursGenerationClass", {
  
  distroHoursGenerationClass <- DrawDistroHoursGenerationClass("test", c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
  
  
  testthat::expect_equal(distroHoursGenerationClass$getModel(), "Draw Distro")
  
  testthat::expect_equal(distroHoursGenerationClass$getName(), "test")
  
  testthat::expect_true(is.numeric(distroHoursGenerationClass$generateHoursFromStorage("test")))
  
}
)
```

With the purpose being I can call the function DrawDistroGenerationClass with a label and a set of values, and generate a function that will randomly draw from that set any time a call it.

The function works, but within my R project I have a unit test (testthat) for this function, and when I run R cmd I get:

2. -methods::setRefClass(...)
3. -methods::setClass(...)
4. -methods::assignClassDef(Class, classDef, where)
5. -base::assign(mname, def, where)

"Error in `assign(mname, def, where)`: cannot add bindings to a locked environment".

I have no idea why this problem is occurring/

I rather not make my input variables global (as they might conflict with other classes), and I'm using the setRefClass method here so I can make many independent versions of this function.

Comment: We cannot begin to diagnose the error until you share the test code that reproduces it.

Comment: RPost updated with test. Running the test by itself passes, but when the test runs using R cmd check (in a project) it fails with the reported error.

Answer (score 0):

A locked environment is usually down to one of two things.

1. Bad comments that end up trying to grab something they're describing.
2. Bad package loading. When packages are loaded in the normal manner not via devtools they get locked down so that R cant modify them.

Looks like you may have some bad comments. But you might also be double calling a package somewhere else other than this code.

Comment: I've removed the comments and re-run the test, and the error stays the same. I'm not sure I understand your #2 comment however.